# How to view dot files (hidden files) in the base directory of a Docker container

Tags: docker, lucee, commandbox

I have a Lucee app running in Commandbox in a Docker container on Centos 7.

```
Docker version 1.13.1, build 0be3e21/1.13.1
CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
Commandbox v5.2.1+00295
Lucee 5.3.7.47
```

The application code is copied to the `/app` directory at startup via the Dockerfile:

```
COPY . /app
```

I would like to view a dot file (hidden file) in the `/app` directory, `/app/.build`.

If I browse to http://app_name.com/.build, I get a 404 error (Not Found).

If I rename the file to build.json by the following command:

```
cp .build build.json
```

then I can view it via http://app_name.com/build.json

I've tried making the following entry in the server.json file:

```
"rewrites":{
    "enable":true,
    "config":"customRewrites.xml"
},
```

And the following rule in the customRewrites.xml file:

```
<rule>
    <from>\.build$</from>
    <set type="content-type">text-html</set>
    <to last="true">\.build</to>
</rule>
```

Adding the complete Dockerfile for more clarity:

```
FROM ortussolutions/commandbox
COPY . /app
COPY ./config/ /config/
ENV LUCEE_EXTENSIONS D4EDFDBD-A9A3-E9AF-597322D767E0C949;name=Oracle;version=11.2.0.4
WORKDIR $APP_DIR
RUN box install
```

After some further investigation, I found that the problem seems to be that the /usr/local/lib/serverHome/WEB-INF/urlrewrite.xml file is not being created at startup. The logs during startup indicate that the rewrites are being read:
--urlrewrite-enable true
--urlrewrite-file /app/customRewrites.xml

Comment: can you add the Dockerfile, please?

Comment: I added the complete Dockerfile for clarity, thanks for asking:

Comment: did you executed this command `cp .build build.json` inside the docker container? I mean did you check that the file, `.build` copied into the docker container?

Comment: are u sure from the syntax of `customRewrites.xml` file? can you have a look [here](https://commandbox.ortusbooks.com/embedded-server/configuring-your-server/url-rewrites#custom-rules).

Comment: Omar, I did check that the files exist in the Docker container
The current Docker container name is "d97aaa01fd38"
root@d97aaa01fd38:/app# pwd
/app
root@d97aaa01fd38:/app# ls -la |grep build
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   152 Feb 23 21:15 .build
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   152 Feb 23 21:15 build.json

Comment: Omar, I found that the server.json file and the customRewrite.xml file seem to be read during the startup from the following log entries:

Comment: Omar, I found that the server.json file and the customRewrite.xml file seem to be read during the startup from the following log entries:
| server config file - /app//server.json
   |     --urlrewrite-enable true
   |     --urlrewrite-file /app/customRewrites.xml

However, the /usr/local/lib/serverHome/WEB-INF/urlrewrite.xml is not being generated. On other systems that I have customRewrites.xml files, the /usr/local/lib/serverHome/WEB-INF/urlrewrite.xml is generated at startup with the contents of the customRewrites.xml.

Comment: okay what I mean... are u sure from the syntax of the customRewrites.xml rule for form tag? shoud u use the forwarded slash rather than backward slash? I think `<from>\.build$</from>` should look like this `<form>^/.build$</form>`

Comment: Omar, I tried changing the "\" to "/", still doesn't work. We are using the "\" to escape the ".". Thanks again for your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

What I have found that the urlRewrite.xml file that comes as a default in Commandbox 5.2 has the following code that blocks hidden files:

```
<rule>
    <condition type="request-uri" operator="equal">.*/\..*</condition>
    <from>^/(.+)$</from>
    <set type="status">404</set>
    <to type="passthrough" last="true">/404.html</to>
</rule>
```